# Trigger Lazyload with fake scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, lazy-loading

I use Lazyload not to load images in hidden divs. When I display my div with an onClick event the images stay hidden. I need to scroll for them to appear.

Is it possible to create a fake scrolling after the div is displayed to trigger Lazyload?

I created a scrollTop event but my page is already at the top so it is not working.

Answer (score 7):

I've seen this issue with Lazy Load also, when if you show a previously hidden div, the page still needs a tiny scroll event to "wake up" the Lazy Load images. So simulate one. 
You can accomplish this instantly and without animation after first calling show on your div:

```
$('body,html').scroll();
```

This will "scroll" the webpage without any page scroll actually noticed by the user, yet it will get the lazy loaded images to load.

Answer (score 0):

Create a scrollBottom event of 1 px.

Sketchy but working.

```
$('body,html').animate({
scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 1
}, 300);
return false
```